# Website Broken in IE8

Tags: wordpress, web, internet-explorer-8

I am working on a Wordpress site (a modified 2012 theme) for a client that is rendering incorrectly in IE8. Everything looks great in IE9+, as well as current versions of Chrome, FF, Safari, etc. I have looked around at some of the suggestions posted to fix the problem but I'm not quite sure where mine begins. The whole page is considerably broken. If anyone can provide me with some clues it would be a huge help. Thanks!

[My Site](http://www.delindesign.com/excellence)

Edit: I'm noticing some of my styles are not being applied, specifically to top-nav and my footer. Others appear to have most if not all styles mostly intact. I've read that media-queries are not supported in IE8, but I don't see how that could be related. I am also reading that only 31 stylesheets can be applied, but I don't believe I am using nearly that many.

Comment: Your question sounds **very general**, there a lot of things changed IE8→IE9. You can check status of availabily of features on http://caniuse.com

Comment: It is a pretty general question. Like I said I looked around for a solution, I'm just not really sure where to start. The link you provided looks very useful, I just need an idea of what to look for first in my markup.

Answer (score 2):

I had a project a while back where I have built an intranet and was nearly finished with the strap when I realized that most of the users rely on IE8; it was a shocking experience, can tell you that. That just as a preamble, so I know what your into.

I have wasted a lot of time so to safe yours (maybe), here what I would *look* for and probably do:

- Install IE8 if you haven't already. There's a lot of tools which can help you with that like [IE Tester](http://ietester.en.softonic.com/) as well as an integration installation from Microsoft directly to switch between versions
- Eradicate the current errors first before you start working on the *specific IE8 issues* (as @markratledge already mentioned)
- If you want to have HTML5 elements *working* as well then I recommend the [HTML5.js Enabling Script](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)
- You have *definitely* too many HTTP Referrers (even for modern browsers), in IE8 (especially on a slower machine) it's sometimes deadly (Your page *may* load fast, however the rendering time is extremely long (+/- 6-20 seconds))
- Combine and minify CSS and JScripts

  - There are a lot of services around the net where you put in your raw data and it compiles you a minified version, or server-side like [Minify for PHP5](https://code.google.com/p/minify/)
- Move most scripts to the bottom to counterfeit rendering issues in IE8
- Make a unique .css only for IE8 or use hacks, if really needed in your main, however you prefer (quick'n'dirty solution though)
- [IE8 and the X-UA-Compatible situation](http://farukat.es/journal/2009/05/245-ie8-and-the-x-ua-compatible-situation)

  - [How IE8 Determines Document Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx)
- I'm not too sure, but I think Mootools and jQuery together *may* create a conflict in older IE's (*assumption*)

> Fix your code errors, in particular the JS call above the doctype. Anything above the doctype throws IE into quirks mode

Especially IE8 will get really hard on you for little mistakes inside the code, I have even seen script-includes not working because of being positioned lower than another in the code (while any other browser doesn't really care). It will take you at least a good bunch of hours to fix/erase all those errors and to make it compatible for IE8< users.

Beware that most clients (at least from my experience) don't (want to) understand browser compatibility issues like this one (*It has to work!*) or if really needed then make them understand that some features may be **jeopardized/incomplete** in the specific browser, herein.

There's plenty more you can do, but that depends on the deadline/timespan you have.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this incredibly detailed response. I will try everything mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code errors, in particular the JS call above the doctype. Anything above the doctype throws IE into quirks mode

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  delindesign.com excellence  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//delindesign.com/excellence/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.